# Can I show different articles to different users in Joomla?

Tags: module, joomla, joomla-article

I want to create a structure in Joomla for users. A different article for different registered users. I do not have groups. For example If I have 3 users, and when they click on a menu (for example, "Info") they see a different article from each other.

User A sees something different when he clicks on info and user B something else and user C something else.

How can I do this; are there any components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no feature in Joomla or extensions that I know of that allows you do this. If you are using Joomla 2.5/3.0, then you will be best off creating different user groups, then creating 3 separate menu items, 1 for each group that only they have access to.

If you are Joomla 1.5, then you only extension that I know of for adding custom user groups is [ArtofUser](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/14383), which is still limited in it's own way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use the newsflash module to show an article from a category - and then put all these articles into this category. Or are these users in different user groups in which case it would be better to simply create an article connected to a menu item for each user group

Comment: upgraded to 2.5 which allows to create groups. Thank you!